# How to move projects between collections of an Azure DevOps server?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, devops

I have installed an Azure DevOps server on my local server and I've created DefaultCollection. After a few months, we add more collections. Now we want to move some projects from DefaultCollection to new collections.

I always choose 'Import' function from 'Repos' section to move all history, branches, commits, pushes of a repository. But when I put an Azure DevOps address, Import function does not work and throws an error:

Import request cannot be processed due to one of the following reasons:

- Clone URL is incorrect.
- Credentials are incorrect.
- Clone URL points to an empty repository.

All reasons FIXed in my process and throws the same error again!
When I change the address to another Git repository of other Git servers(Not DevOps server), it works fine. 
What's the problem with this?

Comment: Check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops

Comment: Currently move projects between collections is not supported. However import repository between collections is working. You can press F12 in the browser when trying to import the repository, just to check if there are any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: @Hessam Hosseini Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this issue ,enabling the movement of projects between collections of an Azure DevOps server is a longstanding request from many customers.

From the [uservoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html) we can know that: enabling team project move would be a huge amount of work due to architectural decisions made way back in the early days of Team Foundation Server. So I am afraid this feature will not be supported in the short term.

Here are some alternate approaches that you can use as a work around:

For Azure DevOps Server you could consider using [Team Project Collection Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/split-team-project-collection?view=azure-devops). This is a good alternative when you need to archive projects, split organizations, or reduce the number of team projects in a single collection, etc. However, this does not help you when you need to merge organizations, or consolidate team project collections.

- [WIMigrator](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator) supports migrating work items between projects.
  However, this tool does not copy Boards artifacts such as sprints,
  plans, dashboards, etc.
- [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) supports migrating work items,
  test suites, and test plans between projects. It also supports
  merging many team projects into a single team project along with
  several other capabilities.
- [VSTeam](https://github.com/DarqueWarrior/vsteam) supports migrating pipelines between projects however
  some code or PowerShell scripting will be required.

Answer (score 0):

try with Migration Tools for Azure DevOps by Martin's, but it is not super simple. check this:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration

Answer (score 0):

It`s not possible now. But this feature can be included into the release plan of Azure DevOps. Vote here: [make it possible to move a Team Project between Team Project Collections](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365365/make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te-1.html)